# Bandwidth Aware Video Streaming

Tags: codec, video-streaming

In the recent Broadcasts of [IPL Matches on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/indiatimes) (Indian Premier League), I noticed that the Video Quality of the live stream degrades and Up-scales according to the bandwidth available.

This is a good way to prevent block-ups in live-streaming and still be able to deliver the broadcast.

**Question:**
What kind of codec and streaming server are required for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Media Ecosystem can do this automatically.

Take a look at [this page](http://www.iis.net/download/ServeMedia), it lists information for the codec, server parts, client parts and more.

If you need any help or further information on this, let me know and I can dig up links to specific questions.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be what I was looking for. I will give it a go and get back to you if I need any further help!

Also, is their something similar for apache/php/flash combination?